# Send a message from a telegram bot at a specific time php

Tags: php, time, bots, telegram

i am trying to develop a simple telegram bot in php. I want my bot to send a message at the same time every day. I tried to insert in the if that checks if I write "/ start" this loop:

```
$tosend = time(); //I find the current time
        while(1)
        {
            sleep(1); 
            if(time() > $tosend)  //If the current time exceeds the recorded one, I send the message
            {
                sendMessage($id, "Ciao");
                $tosend += 3600;
            }
        }
```

It works partially. In addition to the "hello" message he also sends other messages that he shouldn't send, the frequency of sending the message is not one hour (as in the case above) and the rest of the bot is very slow (I think because of the infinite loop). Is there a better method or can I improve this? Thank you all

Comment: If you want to send something on a schedule, instead of trying to time it in PHP, just configure a cron job to execute your PHP script at the relevant time.

Comment: ok I hadn't thought about this solution but I don't think it's possible in my case because my bot is hosted on a site for web pages, not for bots.  This way the code starts when it receives a message.  I could for example use the IFTTT service.  Thanks for the reply

Comment: Most Web hosting supports cron jobs these days

Answer (score 1):

About the other messages it sends, it should be the default branch of a switch statement you put in the code.

About the frequency, I think it is a Telegram problem, I also had it with no errors, but it can be resolved storing the informations you need on a .txt file on the host, to avoid sending the same message in the same hour, I try making a script for you:

```
if(!file_exists("check.txt")){
    $myfile = fopen("check.txt", "w+");
    fwrite($myfile, time());
    fclose($myfile);
}
while(true){
    $read = file("check.txt");
    $tosend = $read[0];
    $tosend += 3600;
    while(true){
        if(time() < $tosend){
            sleep(1); 
        }else{
            $myfile = fopen("check.txt", "w+");
            fwrite($myfile, time());
            fclose($myfile);
            sendMessage($id, "Ciao");
            break 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope this will be useful, I put a lot of effort in it, if you have questions ask them